# How to make Flutter Stepper body expand to fill entire screen height

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Because Flutter Stepper is scrollable, it can't be set the step content to fill its height.

I want to make a layout like this
[image]

While I'm getting this layout
[image]

I've used `SizedBox` with fixed height, but it's incorrect way while screens have different height values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use SizedBox , just specify a non-fixed height and get the current screen height via

MediaQuery. of(context). size. height

this is how it works normally regardless of the screen size

```
Step(
  isActive: currentStep >=0,
  title: Text('Account'),
  content: SizedBox(
    height: MediaQuery. of(context). size. height - 300,
    child: Text("sdf"),),
),
```